# Prolog: List of succeeding sub-rules

Tags: prolog

Let's say I have the following rule in Prolog (I am using SWI-Prolog):

```
rule :-
    subrule_1 ;
    subrule_2 ;
    subrule_3 ;

    ...

    subrule_n.
```

So "rule" succeeds whenever one of the sub-rules does. I know that as soon as one sub-rule succeeds the others will not be executed. What I want to do is add functionality so that ALL subrules are executed, and create a list of the subrules that succeeded. But "rule" should still fail when none succeed. So far this is all I can think of:

```
...
rule(Successes), % This is the external call
...
```

And the rule is:

```
rule(Succeed_List) :-
    L1 = [],
    ((subrule_1 -> append(L1,['subrule_1'],L2) ; L2 = L1) ,
    (subrule_2 -> append(L2,['subrule_2'],L3) ; L3 = L2) ,
    ...
    (subrule_n -> append(Ln,['subrule_n'],Succeed_List) ; Succeed_List = Ln)),
    \+ length(Succeed_List,0).
```

Surely there must be a better way to do this! I was thinking of using "bagof" but I am not sure how that would work. My question is, what is a better way of implementing the rule above?

For those wondering "what on earth could those subrules possibly be", I am omitting a lot of details here in terms of what I'm trying to do. If you want to know, each subrule has one argument, the same for each. It is a term with arity 8 but every argument is an atom already bound. The subrules examine the arguments of the term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that bagof/3 can do a big part of your task:

```
rule(Succeed_List) :-
    bagof(P, (member(P, [subrule_1, subrule_2, .., subrule_n]), P), Succeed_List).
```

you could remove the big argument from P using functor:

```
rule(Succeed_List) :-
    bagof(F, (member(P, [subrule_1, subrule_2, .., subrule_n]), P, functor(P, F,_)), Succeed_List).
```